# Need a hint to evaluate $\lim_{x\to +\infty}{x-\sin x \over x+\sin x}$

Tags: calculus, limits, trigonometry, limits-without-lhopital

I Need a hint to evaluate $\lim\limits_{x\to +\infty} \dfrac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x}$
I was doing the following
$$-1\le \sin x \le1$$
$$1 \ge -\sin x \ge -1$$
$$ {x+1 \over x+\sin x} \ge {x-\sin x \over x + \sin x} \ge {x-1 \over x+\sin x}$$
Now I think, by Squeeze Theorem, that $\lim_{x\to +\infty}{x-\sin x \over x+\sin x}=1$

Is there other way to solve it without L'Hopital's rule?

Comment: The inequalities are backwards in your second displayed line: as written, they say that $1\le-1$.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott You are right!

Comment: You couldn't do this **with** L'Hôpital's rule, even if you wanted to.

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/528661/finding-the-limit-of-frac-sqrtx-sqrtx-sin-sqrtx

Answer (score 7, accepted):

$x > 2,$
$$ 1 - \frac{2}{x+1} = \frac{x-1}{x+1} \leq   \frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x} \leq  \frac{x+1}{x-1} =  1 + \frac{2}{x-1}  $$

Comment: $x > 1$ should be enough.

Comment: @HenningMakholm, yes, but this way is more hygge

Answer (score 10):

HINT:

$$\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x}=\frac{1-\frac{\sin x}x}{1+\frac{\sin x}x}$$

Answer (score 0):

*A bit overkill*, but gives the second-order term as well:

If you are familiar with Taylor expansions? Rewriting your expression as 
$$
\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x} = \frac{1-\frac{\sin x}{x}}{1+\frac{\sin x}{x}}
$$
yand observing that $\frac{\sin x}{x}\xrightarrow[x\to\infty]{}0$, you can use the fact that $\frac{1}{1+y} = 1-y + o(y)$ when $y\to 0$.

You will get 
$$
\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x} = (1-\frac{\sin x}{x})(1-\frac{\sin x}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)) = 1-2\frac{\sin x}{x}+o\left(\frac{1}{x}\right)
$$
which gives the limit (and a bit more).

Comment: Sometimes, i get a tad carried away with Taylor expansions.

Comment: There is a nearby park with a long, narrow pond. About 45 minutes to walk around. Calms me down. Taylor expansions are not my particular problem, I think the principle would still apply.

Answer (score 0):

It's shorter with *equivalents*, as often: $x\pm \sin x\sim_\infty x$, hence:
$$\frac{x-\sin x}{x+\sin x}\sim_\infty\frac xx=1. $$

Comment: Oops! Thanks for pointing the typo!